# Installation and Configuring OF Oracle Identity and Access Management-12.2.1.3.0

Tags: oracle

To install Oracle Identity and Access Management-12.2.1.3.0, I am following the steps given at https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/idmsuite/INOAM/toc.htm  link. First I did the installation of **WebLogic and created WebLogic domain**. Then I did the installation of **Oracle SOA Suite and Oracle Business Process** because it is needed for Oracle Identity Governance.  My problem is that according to given steps, I executed RCU and created schema in SOA suite installation with prefix DEV then again executed RCU and created the schema with prefix DEV1 in the installation of the Oracle Identity and Access Management. Now again in Configuring the Oracle Identity Governance Domain, given steps are asking to execute RCU and create schema. I am not getting, RCU and schema creation is one time task or recursive task. If it is recursive, i have to create multiple schemas with the different prefix so which one will be the working schema?

Answer (score 1):

you found the correct link to purchase. actually you have to define seperated domains and individual RCU configs and schemas.
the prefixes for Identity and Access should be different. 
actually as you mentioned, you have to define 2 different prefixes for  installing access (OAM), and Identity (IDM), to understand they're in same groups. multiple schemas with 2 different prefixes are created automatically.
when you want to create the IDM(identiy), the bellow schema is going to be set:
for example by prefix of "IDMDEV":
IDMDEV_OIM
and you are going to repeat the password for it.
actually there is a good link and kind of summary of installing of IDM is [here](http://avijit-sengupta.blogspot.nl/2017/10/oim-12c-installation-with-quick.html).